# Webpack config loaders error when using postcss autoprefixer

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

**So i have been using webpack with loaders. Today i wanted to add a prefixer loader to css and i keep getting error at webpack dev server run that "cannot resolve module postcss" here is the code:**

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css?{"sourceMap&modules&localIdentName": "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]", "modules&importLoader": "1!postcss"}'}
    ]
  },
  postcss: [ autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }) ]
```

**before this i had been using just the below code and my webpack run dev server command ran without error.**

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css?sourceMap&modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'}
    ]
  }
```

**what am i doing wrong?**

Comment: Have you installed [post-css-loader](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader) (`npm install postcss-loader --save-dev`)?

Comment: Yes i have.  and the autoprefixer plugin

Answer (score 0):

solved it:

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css?sourceMap&modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]&importLoader=1!postcss'}
    ]
  },
  postcss: [ autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }) ]
```